# How to append date time for each output sql statement when executing sql file?

Tags: db2

I have a sql file test.sql,

```
test.sql:
---------
drop table a.table1;
drop table a.table2;
drop table a.table3;
drop table a.table4;
drop table a.table5;
```

Now I want to execute test.sql by

```
db2  -tvf test.sql > result.log
```

The goal I want to achieve is to append a date time for output of each sql statement, the date time can be of any format and should be the one when executing the corresponding sql statement, now suppose each drop statement need 1 sec to execute, the result.log should be like this:

```
result.log:
-----------
Wed Dec 6 18:46:41 HKT 2017  DB20000I The SQL Command Completed Successfully.
Wed Dec 6 18:46:42 HKT 2017  DB20000I The SQL Command Completed Successfully.
Wed Dec 6 18:46:43 HKT 2017  DB20000I The SQL Command Completed Successfully.
Wed Dec 6 18:46:44 HKT 2017  DB20000I The SQL Command Completed Successfully.
Wed Dec 6 18:46:45 HKT 2017  DB20000I The SQL Command Completed Successfully.
```

Any idea how to achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use -l to set a log file.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html.  You can also SELECT CURRENT_DATE 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; to echo the datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, now I can do it with

```
db2 -l result.log -tvf test.sql > /dev/null
```